# Как принудительно свернуть список в ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Как принудительно свернуть список в  `ExpandableListView`?  Например, мне нужно свернуть список после того, как пользователь нажал на `child` элемент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно так:

```
mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(mGroupPosition);
```

Или если не сработает то смотри [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17586315/5634351)

Comment: Кирилл, спасибо, работает!